# Does DnssdServiceInstance work on Windows IoT

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to get DNS-SD working on windows 10 IoT but i can't see the advertisement to working. RegisterStreamSocketListenerAsync returns success so I'm not sure why its not working.

```
namespace BackgroundApplication1
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
        private StreamSocketListener _socket;
        private DnssdServiceInstance _service;

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            try
            {
                // Create a listening socket to watch for incoming connections from other apps 
                _socket = new StreamSocketListener();

                await _socket.BindServiceNameAsync("2222", SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

                // Create a DNS-SD Service Instance 
                DnssdServiceInstance chatServ =
                                     new DnssdServiceInstance("SimpleChatApp._sca._tcp.local.", null, 2222);

                // Can add optional text attributes (key-val pairs) as well
                chatServ.TextAttributes.Add("MaxConcurrentUsers", "20");
                chatServ.TextAttributes.Add("Locale", "En-US");

                // Register Service
                var registrationResult
                                   = await chatServ.RegisterStreamSocketListenerAsync(_socket);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }        
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of your windows iot device?

Comment: It's a raspberry pi 3

Comment: Using the insider build

Comment: Do you mean you never receive any connection request?

Comment: I don't see the service being advertised. I'm using a dns-sd app on my laptop and a app on my phone and I can't see it..

Comment: We're trying to do exactly the same thing but don't have any success. Did you ever get this to work?